# Useful value for rate of change

Tags: time-series, trend, derivative

I want to create a simple representation of "rate of change" for a number of different metrics, which aren't really comparable between each-other. To illustrate my problem, let's say I have the following metrics: temperature in Celsius, temperature in Fahrenheit, and air pressure in mbar.
Each metric supplies a continuous stream of data points.
For each of these points, I want to illustrate the "trend", i.e., if the metric is going up or down, and ideally by *how much*. However, for each such calculation I only have access to two values - the most recent value (let's call it `x0`) and the previous value (let's call it `x1`). I know the time in between these two data points.

So first I thought I'd just illustrate the rate of change by the time derivative, so I did `(x1 - x0) / (t1 - t0)`. This of course gives an indication of how this metric has changed (and *possibly* where it's heading).

However, this value for rate of change isn't really comparable between different metrics, because e.g. a change of 10 for Celsius temperature represents almost twice as much as a change of 10 for Fahrenheit temperature, and isn't at all comparable to a change of 10 for air pressure in mbar.
So then I thought I'd use the fraction of change, so I used `(x1 - x0) / x0`, which tells you by how much the value changed relative to its previous value. But there are at least two problems here:

1. This ignores how quickly the change was made - were the two values 1 minute apart or 1 hour apart?
2. This is also skewed as a comparison between different metrics: a change in Celsius temperature from 10 to 20°C is a 100% increase, but represents the same physical temperature change of 50 to 68°F, which is just 36%. This also makes the rate of change values impossible to compare to each other.

This also illustrates that saying "it's twice as warm as yesterday" doesn't really make sense neither in Celsius nor Fahrenheit.

Even using a combination of these to use "percentage of change per time unit" doesn't fix problem 2.

So I guess I need to normalize my rate of change value somehow. For temperature, perhaps actually using the difference in K is the only thing that makes "physical" sense (as it's proportial to the kinetic energy). But when comparing completely different metrics such as temperature vs air pressure, I just don't have any clue.

Am I making this too complicated or is it just a bad idea to even try to have a comparable rate of change more refined than having three values "going up", "going down" and "the same"? Is it feasible to come up with something that makes it possible to illustrate that a temperature is going "rapidly up" while air pressure has just gone "slightly up" in the last hour without having custom formulas for each metric (such as percentage of change measured Kelvin per time unit for temperature)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the data and are analyzing it retrospectively, you could calculate all of the individual measures' interval rates of change, and then express them *relative to the average rate of change* for that measure. To do this, calculate $m_i=(x_i-x_{i-1})/(t_i-t_{i-1})$ for one measure for every interval, find the average rate of change over all intervals ($\bar m$), and then express interval rates of change as $m_i/ \bar m$. This gives you measure-specific values as to whether the measure is changing more or less than average, which could be a reasonable way to express "changing a lot" or "changing a little".

You may have to weight the formula if your intervals are not of equal length. There may also be numerical issues if most of your intervals exhibit no change, as even small fluctuations will look relatively huge compared to no change at all. This also requires retrospective analysis of the data, as you need the full history to compute the average. You could alter this for prospective analysis if you have domain knowledge about roughly what's an "average" rate of change - simply replace $\bar m$ with whatever value you choose, and this becomes your new setpoint for comparison for what constitutes a big or little change.

Comment: The main problem with such an approach, as you hint, is that when time intervals vary, your $m_i$ can have *hugely* varying variances.  Ordinarily this is solved using suitable weights (made complicated by the correlations induced among the $m_i$) or, more simply, by using rank-based procedures, such as Sen's slope estimate.  Ultimately, though, the very general question being asked is unanswerable, because there is no universal way to make one kind of quantity (or changes thereof) commensurate with every other kind.